# Revit Macro Manager C# Error

Tags: c#, macros, revit, revit-api

I am trying to create a macro using c# in revit. I am getting 3 errors.
i) The name 'WallSection' does not exist in the current context (CS0103)
ii) The name 'WallLayerDimensions' does not exist in the current context (CS0103)
iii) Then name 'ViewOnSheet' does not exist in the current context (CS0103)

Can anybody help with this errors.

Comment: Post code as well and exact error.

Comment: Thanks Neel, I solve the errors. I missed the namespace but i am unable to run the macro its showing error Revit Run Macro Failed. Can you give me your email Id i will send you the code.

Comment: Thanks Neel, I solve the errors. I missed the namespace but i am unable to run the macro its showing error Revit Run Macro Failed. Can you give me your email Id i will send you the code.

Comment: Code is quite big. How do i post?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing required namespace... but could not find the classes you point out on the Revit 2015 SDK.

Which Revit version?

Comment: Thanks Augusto, I solve the errors. I missed the namespace but i am unable to run the macro its showing error Revit Run Macro Failed. Can you give me your email Id i will send you the code.

Comment: Code is quite Big. How do i post?